# browserify - exclude code blocks?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, browserify

I'm building an app with shared React components in the browser and server-side Node.

Right now, I'm using Marty.js to do this:

```
function getUser() {
    if (Marty.isBrowser) {
        /* Get user using some client method */  
    } else {
        /* otherwise, use some secret server code */
    }
}
```

I'm bundling those functions up via Browserify, so they can run on the client as well as the server.

What I'd like to do is remove the `else` block from the bundle entirely, so I'm not leaking sensitive server-side code.

Is there a way to exclude blocks of code from the bundle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would create separate modules, one for the browser and one for the server. Then in your `package.json`, you tell browserify to use the browser module:

```
"browser": {
    "./path/to/node-module.js": "./path/to/browser-module.js"
}
```

Now, whereever you call `require('path/to/node-module')`, browserify will load the other module instead.

---

More information from the [docs](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#browser-field):

> **browser field**
>
> There is a special "browser" field you can set in your package.json on a per-module basis to override file resolution for browser-specific versions of files.
>
> For example, if you want to have a browser-specific module entry point for your "main" field you can just set the "browser" field to a string:
>
> ```
> "browser": "./browser.js"
> ```
>
> or you can have overrides on a per-file basis:
>
> ```
> "browser": {
>   "fs": "level-fs",
>   "./lib/ops.js": "./browser/opts.js"
> }
> ```
>
> Note that the browser field only applies to files in the local module, and like transforms, it doesn't apply into node_modules directories.

Answer (score 2):

While I'm not sure if it possible with Browserify, you can do it with Webpack using its DefinePlugin

From the [docs](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/list-of-plugins#defineplugin) (little modified):

> Example:
>
> ```
> new webpack.DefinePlugin({
>     DEBUG: false,
>     PRODUCTION: true,
>     ...
> })
> ```
>
> ...
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> if(DEBUG)
>     console.log('Debug info')
> if(PRODUCTION)
>     console.log('Production log')
> ```
>
> After passing through webpack with no minification results in:
>
> ```
> if(false)
>     console.log('Debug info')
> if(true)
>     console.log('Production log')
> ```
>
> and then after a minification pass results in:
>
> ```
> console.log('Production log')
> ```

Comment: Excellent answer. Your webpack config most likely uses DefinePlugin already to set the 'process.env.NODE_ENV' setting.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an environment variable, [envify](https://github.com/hughsk/envify) and [uglify](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2) to do this.

```
if ('browser' === process.env.ENVIRONMENT) {
  ...
}
else {
  ...
}
```

Set `process.env.ENVIRONMENT = 'browser'` when doing your browser build, use the envify transform to substitute references to `process.env` with their current values and uglify will then perform dead code elimination to remove the branches which will never be hit.

Comment: +1 for the tip on dead code elimination - I was unaware that uglify did this. Of course, this step only assumes minified code... in my dev environment, I use full source + source maps, which would still still expose the functionality.

Answer (score 0):

What about putting the code in a module for example `UserServer` and then exclude that module when you are compiling for the client? Your code becomes:

```
function getUser() {
    if (Marty.isBrowser) {
        /* Get user using some client method */  
    } else { 
       require('UserServer').getUser();
    }
}
```

Browserify provides the following option to exclude files from the bundle:

```
--exclude, -u  Omit a file from the output bundle. Files can be globs.
```

Answer (score 0):

Be more explicit about your intent, and put your code in their own files:

```
function getUser(options, callback) {
  var fn;
  if (Marty.isBrowser) {
      fn = require("./lib/users/get.browser");
  } else {
      fn = require("./lib/users/get.server");
  }
  fn(options, callback);
}
```

and then as a browserify option you can say "replace `require("./lib/users/get.server")` with this variable instead, when you see it: ..." so that you don't build in that server file when you build for the browser.

However, if getUser can do different things based on where it's running, it feels far more likely that you're doing something wrong here: maybe that getUser should be a REST call to your server from the browser instead, but without more information, that's always hard to determine.

Comment: In the browser, it's a REST call. In Node, it's a local DB call. It's the same back-end API, with two different entry points (in the browser, sessions and various other things are checked first.) The point is to be able to generate a SSR'd view of the initial render (regardless of the URL) and throw that back to the browser, with all subsequent calls from the browser.